# exist() Returns Unexpected Outupt With Dynamic Fieldname Inputs

Tags: matlab, struct, field

If you type:

```
MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString).Values = [1 2 3];
```

And then attempt to use `exist`:

```
exist('MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString).Values')
```

It returns `0`, where I expect the output to be `1`.

`exist` doesn't seem to work with dynamic fieldnames because:

```
MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString).Values
```

Returns:

```
ans =
     1     2     3
```

How do I check for existence of the last field in the structure?

Comment: I solved it like this, but it is ugly :)

Comment: `exist` is to check for the existence of a variable, function, folder, or class. A field of a structure is not one of those things. This doesn't work with explicit field names either. Use [`isfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfield.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use try and catch.
If your expression fails it means that your field is missing.

try

MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString).Values;

isExist = true;

catch err

isExist = false;

end

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
if isfield( MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS,'MetaLegendHandles')

        if isfield( MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles,CurrSelIndType)

            if isfield(MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType),CurrTransMethodString)

                if isfield(MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString),'Values')
                    % do nothing
                else
                    MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString).Values = [];
                end

            else
                MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString).Values = [];
            end
        else
            MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString).Values = [];
        end    

    else
        MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString).Values = [];
    end
```

Comment: Why is `isfield(MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString), 'Values')` not acceptable but `exist('MetaSelIndPlotPARAMS.MetaLegendHandles.(CurrSelIndType).(CurrTransMethodString).Values')` would be?